# store fetched data and use in components in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I want to fetch data from my server and use it in components but when I fetched data I don't want to keep sending requests to my server.

When a user logs in, I fetch its data and store it in SET_USER_INFO.

```
async login({ commit, state }, account) {
        try{
            await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(account.email, account.password);

            if(!auth.currentUser.emailVerified){
                throw {
                        error: "Email didnot verified!",
                        code: "auth/email-unverified"
                    }
            }
            const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
            const { email, uid } = auth.currentUser;
    
            Cookie.set('access_token', token);

            commit('SET_USER', { email, uid });

            const path = '/api/fetch_user_info';
            const res = await this.$axios.get(path);
            commit('SET_USER_INFO', res.data);
```

but when I try to reach the data from components, it is undefined

```
methods: {
        test() {
            this.user_info = this.$store.state.users.user_info;
            console.log(this.$store.state.users.user_info);
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.test();
    },
```

I tried to fetch data in nuxtServerInit function but still I cannot reach data from middleware functions. I tried a lot of things. If it is not clear, I can add details.

Comment: Also I am not sure if it is safe to store some insensetive user information in Cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Okey I find out a valid solution.

I add following lines to the middleware function:

```
export default async function ({ store, route, redirect, from, req }) {
    if (!from){
        let token = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie).access_token;
        console.log('request send');
        await store.dispatch('users/getUserInfo', token);
    }
}
```

and my getUserInfo looks like this:

```
async getUserInfo({ commit }, token=null) {
        let access_token;
        (token != null) ? access_token = token : access_token = Cookie.get('access_token');
        const path = '/api/get_user_info';
        const res = await this.$axios.get(path, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
            },});
        commit('SET_USER_INFO', res.data);
}
```

I think this is a valid solution. If you share your comments, I would be glad

reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSbahlvDfS4